# pip + how to download the latest version of the .whl files

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ansible, rhel

Is it possible to download the latest version of `.whl` files?

for example, first, we try with  pip download some specific version of `enum34`

```
pip download enum34-1.1.10-py2-none-any.whl
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
WARNING: Requirement 'enum34-1.1.10-py2-none-any.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Processing ./enum34-1.1.10-py2-none-any.whl
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/download.py", line 132, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=True
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 179, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 362, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 314, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 469, in prepare_linked_requirement
    hashes=hashes,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 264, in unpack_url
    unpack_file(file.path, location, file.content_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/unpacking.py", line 252, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/unpacking.py", line 112, in unzip_file
    zipfp = open(filename, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/tmp/enum34-1.1.10-py2-none-any.whl'
```

then we try to download the latest version of `enum34*`

```
pip download enum34*
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'enum34*'
```

Comment: Which  OS do you use?

Comment: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip download enum34`

Comment: rhel 7.5 this is the os

Comment: @jessica try this then;  `yum install python-enum34`

Comment: `pip` doesn't respect wildcards. `pip download enum34` downloads the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pip download enum34` as there is no package named such as `enum34*` as shown below in the image. [correct syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9vXT.png)

Comment: it is about upgrade and what I want is download

Comment: try pip install enum34

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/ it says _`pip` download does the same resolution and downloading as pip install, but instead of installing the dependencies, it collects the downloaded distributions into the directory provided (defaulting to the current directory). This directory can later be passed as the value to pip install --find-links to facilitate offline or locked down package installation._

Comment: doc say -  pip download SomePackage , but why its failed on pip download enum34*

Comment: have you tried without * in `enum34*` such as `pip download enum34`